# Duplicate Data Issue when Storing JSON Messages in Azure Storage Queue using Azure Functions in Go

Tags: azure, go, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

Now I am trying to develop an application using Azure Functions and Go, utilizing Custom Handler.
The architecture of my application is like this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHMsw.png)

The problem seems to lie in storing a  JSON message in an Azure Storage Queue.
The message stored in queue has a duplicate data in its “data” and “metadata” .

My function 1, which is triggered by a HTTP Response from Slack and enqueues a message to the queue, is like this.

```
func function1(c *gin.Context) {
    log.Printf(“Start enqueueMessage”)

    // I use a JSON string here instead of an actual HTTP Request for an easy understanding
    stri := "{\"aaa\" : \"aaa\"}"
    base64BodyString := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(stri)

    _ulr, err := url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf(“https://%s.queue.core.windows.net/%s”, accountName, queueName))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(“Error parsing url: “, err)
    }

    credential, err := azqueue.NewSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(“Error creating shared key credential: “, err)
    }

    queueUrl := azqueue.NewQueueURL(*_ulr, azqueue.NewPipeline(credential, azqueue.PipelineOptions{}))
    ctx := context.TODO()

    messageUrl := queueUrl.NewMessagesURL()
    _, err = messageUrl.Enqueue(ctx, base64BodyString, 0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(“Error enqueueing message: “, err)
    }
    log.Printf(“Message enqueued successfully”)
}
```

Then, my function 2, which is fired by a Queue trigger and processes the message dequeued from the queue, is like this.

```
func function2(c *gin.Context) {

    log.Printf(“Start function”)

    type QueueMessage struct {
      Data struct {
         MyQueueItem string `json:"myQueueItem"`
      } `json:"data"`
      Metadata map[string]interface{}
    }

    var queueMessage QueueMessage
    err := c.BindJSON(&queueMessage)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(“Failed to bind request body: %v”, err)
        return
    }

        log.Printf(“Queue message : %v”, queueMessage)
}
```

The outputs data is like this.

```
{
  "message": "{\"token\": \"aaa\"}",
  "metadata": {
    "DequeueCount": 1,
    "ExpirationTime": "2023-08-01T13:25:29+00:00",
    "Id": "e2b5f133-cc27-46d5-92a8-0305251e65e7",
    "InsertionTime": "2023-07-25T13:25:29+00:00",
    "NextVisibleTime": "2023-07-25T13:35:31+00:00",
    "PopReceipt": "AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAifLM4fy+2QE=",
    "sys": {
      "MethodName": "function2",
      "RandGuid": "9cdd85fc-9522-437a-8b2c-cc4ac4919ad4",
      "UtcNow": "2023-07-25T13:25:31.364779Z"
    },
    "token": "aaa"
  }
}
```

When I stored a message like “hoge” instead of a JSON message, it didn’t contain duplicate data.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

I would like to store a message without duplicate data in Azure Storage Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Storage Queue message is caused by the way you're encoding the JSON payload before enqueuing it  and  base64 encoding the JSON string and then passing it as the message body the message is dequeued and processed, we  are binding it to the `QueueMessage` struct, which expects a specific structure with `data` and `metadata` fields.

```
func function1(c *gin.Context) {
    log.Printf("Start enqueueMessage")

    payload := map[string]string{
        "myQueueItem": "aaa",
    }

    payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error marshaling JSON: ", err)
    }

    base64BodyString := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(payloadBytes)

    _url, err := url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.queue.core.windows.net/%s", accountName, queueName))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error parsing url: ", err)
    }

    credential, err := azqueue.NewSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating shared key credential: ", err)
    }

    queueUrl := azqueue.NewQueueURL(*_url, azqueue.NewPipeline(credential, azqueue.PipelineOptions{}))
    ctx := context.TODO()

    messageUrl := queueUrl.NewMessagesURL()
    _, err = messageUrl.Enqueue(ctx, base64BodyString, 0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error enqueueing message: ", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Message enqueued successfully")
}
```

```
func function2(c *gin.Context) {
    log.Printf("Start function")

    type QueueMessage struct {
        MyQueueItem string `json:"myQueueItem"`
    }

    var queueMessage QueueMessage
    err := c.BindJSON(&queueMessage)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to bind request body: %v", err)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("Queue message : %v", queueMessage)
}
```

- The duplicate data in the message is actually introduced by Azure Functions when it processes the incoming request and stores it in the Azure Storage Queue. When you store a simple string like "hoge" directly as the message content, Azure Functions doesn't add any additional metadata, hence no duplicates.
- The duplicate data in the message is actually introduced by Azure Functions when it processes the incoming request and stores it in the Azure Storage Queue. When you store a simple string like "hoge" directly as the message content, Azure Functions doesn't add any additional metadata, hence no duplicates.
- To avoid this duplicate data, you can modify your `function1` to enqueue a message without using Azure Function's built-in response serialization
- For more details Azure storage queue [go](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-queue-go)

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Now I fully understood it.